# How to write data to HBase with Spark usring Java API?

Tags: hbase, apache-spark

I'm trying to bulk-load the content of a Spark JavaPairRDD to a HBase table.

Is there an example of Java code for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not much examples about how to do this and no specific connector. For now, you have to write rdd using HBase default client.

[Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-944) you have an example using aggregate metrics to hbase using spark streaming.  Translate it to your use case.

Comment: Ok,I'll try it.Thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the open source unicredit library for HBase to Bulk Load data from Spark.

Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/unicredit/hbase-rdd

The library provides an easy interface for bulk loading. It automates both the steps for bulk loading i.e.

1. Creating HFiles from your RDD
2. Loading/Merging those HFiles in the HBase regions.

Here is the link to the bulk load sample: https://github.com/unicredit/hbase-rdd-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/unicredit/example/WriteBulk.scala